# angular-ui-tinymce not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, tinymce

I am using npm (not bower) to download angular-ui-tinymce.

```
npm install angular-ui-tinymce
```

Thereafter, I am installing it in my application using the following.

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
...
require('angular-ui-tinymce');
```

Then, I am including it as a dependency.

```
angular.module('nxch-ies-admin', ['ui.router', ..., 'ui.tinymce']);
```

Finally, I am adding this to my html code...

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="fooContent" placeholder="..."></textarea>
```

And controller as follows.

```
$scope.fooContent = "<div>blah blah blah</div>";

$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    plugins: 'link image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
};
```

But it doesn't work! What am I missing?

Comment: check for console errors, devtools > network tab, few files might not be loaded because of `baseURL` related issues (common with tinymce)

Comment: That's the first place I checked.... but nothing! I get no errors. I am really confused!

Comment: in network tab, some files won't be loaded probably.. what's your baseURL? You tried changing baseURL?

Comment: Try printing fooContent anywhere else on the view. To check if view has the same controller.

Comment: @AmitMalik Yes, printing it elsewhere works.

Comment: can you check in the developer tools-> sources if angular tinymce scripts are loaded ?

Comment: @tanmay As you realise, I am not including the scripts manually in my html.  I am using browserify to bundle everything together, and then referencing that bundle. However, I do note that the documenation for tinymce seems to ask us to reference `tinymce-dist/tinymce.js` as well as `angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js`, so maybe that's where I am going wrong. I simply just installed angular-ui-tinymce and referenced it. I am not sure if that will cover both requirements.

Comment: @AmitMalik I just went through the bundle.js and found tinymce related code to be present. So I guess it is being loaded.

Comment: @tanmay As for the baseURL, I don't know if this is directly related... but I did try and get rid of the `#!` from angular, and so have `<base href="/">` in my index.html. Does that matter?

Comment: @Grateful I am talking about [this base url](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/#document_base_url)

Comment: have you added tinymce.js as dependency like while using require you need to add shim and in that you need to specify tinymce as dependency of angular-ui-tinymce

Comment: @tanmay Oh no, I haven't done that... should I?

Comment: @Grateful you got any better option than trying out? :D

Comment: @AmitMalik I have only added `require("angular-ui-tinymice")`. Secondly, I am not sure what you mean by "you need to add shim".

Comment: Please check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce
Apart from angular-tiny-mce.js you also need tinymce.js script

Comment: @AmitMalik Yes, I have seen that. However, I just realised that although the documentation for angular-ui-tinymce is missing this information... necessary to do `require("tinymce")` as well!

Comment: @AmitMalik I just tried `require("tinymce")` and it seems to be giving me errors. Errors like "theme.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and "plugin.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and "Uncaught TypeError: Theme is not a constructor"... does anyone know why? I have already done `require("tinymce")` and `require("angular-ui-tinymce")`.

Comment: Okay, for now... I have ended up with `require("angular-ui-tinymce")` and just manually adding `<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>` within index.html. Things are finally working!

Answer (score 0):

`require("angular-ui-tinymce")` and manually adding `<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>` within index.html finally gets things to work!

Comment: How to use it via npm? If I dont want to add script by hardcode in index.html ho can I use it via npm? I have tried to install package with npm and then `require('tinymce');` but it still does not work...